# Unable to establish RDP connection to my Amazon instance (windows server) after changing primary DNS setting

Tags: amazon-ec2

I created a Windows Instance (with private IP) and added to my existing VPC. Everything went fine. I was trying to join the new instance to my existing Active Directory. While doing that I had amended the Primary DNS server to ensure that the new instance can read the Domain Controller.

Now, I am unable to connect to the server through RDP.  Tracert says "Destination host unreachable".

Any suggestions?

Regards, Saurabh

Answer (score 0):

I think I was able to solve the problem by creating a new network interface and associating with my instance. This allowed me to RDP .

Regards,
Saurabh